# Make @JsonAnySetter work with @Value Lombok

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I have a json object with a lot of properties (~80 properties) I want to deserialize in a POJO without creating manually all the properties. I was able to do this by using the `@JsonAnySetter` with a `Map` property like described [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/jackson-any-setter.html).

Now I want to make this work by making my POJO immutable using Lombok.
I tried this but it does only deserialize the `id` and `code` properties. Any idea on how to make it work?

```
@Value
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Product.ProductBuilder.class)
class Product {

   @JsonProperty
   private String id;
   @JsonProperty
   private String code;
   @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   @Builder.Default
   @JsonProperty
   private Map<String, Optional<Object>> any = new HashMap<>();

   @JsonAnyGetter
   public  Map<String, Optional<Object>> getAny(){
       return this.any;
   }

   @JsonAnySetter
   public void setAny(String key, Optional<Object> value){
      this.any.put(key, value);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update 2021-02-01: Lombok v1.18.16*

Starting with v1.18.16, Lombok automatically copies `@JsonAnySetter` to the `@Singular` methods in builder. In combination with `@Jacksonized` you can simply use this code:

```
@Value
@Jacksonized
@Builder
class Product {
    private String id;
    private String code;

    @JsonAnySetter
    @Singular("any")
    private Map<String, Object> any;
}
```

*Older Lombok versions*

For previous Lombok version, this requires some customization of the generated builder class.

Customizing a lombok builder can be done by simply adding its inner class header to your class. Lombok detects that there is already a builder class and just adds all the things that are not already present. This means you can add your own methods, and if those happen to have the same name than a method that lombok would generate, lombok skips this method.

With this approach, we replace the builder's setter method for "any", adding the required `@JsonAnySetter` to it. I use a `LinkedHashMap` as map in case the order is relevant; you can use a regular `HashMap` if it's not.

Furthermore, we replace the `build()` method to make sure the map you supply to the constructor is immutable. I use Guava's `ImmutableMap` here. This will make the created instance an immutable value.

```
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Product.ProductBuilder.class)
class Product {

    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String code;

    @Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonAnyGetter)
    private Map<String, Object> any;
    
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class ProductBuilder {
        @JsonAnySetter
        public ProductBuilder any(String anyKey, Object anyValue) {
            if (this.any == null) {
                this.any = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            }
            this.any.put(anyKey, anyValue);
            return this;
        }
        
        public Product build() {
            return new Product(id, code, any == null ? ImmutableMap.of() : ImmutableMap.copyOf(any));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped even though I had a similar issue with @JsonAnyGetter. In my case, to make Jackson work with Lombok I only had to apply `@Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonAnyGetter)` before the `Map` field. I didn't use @Jacksonized, @Builder or @Singular. I'm posting this just in case it could be helpful to others! Thanks again!